# In Scenekit how coefficient of friction applies between pair of materials

Tags: scenekit, game-physics

I am learning `SceneKit` and inside physics section, there is option of setting friction of any object.
I have 2 question regarding that

1. What kind of friction it is? (Static or Kinetic)
2. Given coefficient of friction for system of 2 objects, how can I assign value of `friction` property in SceneKit so that it matches real world physics

e.g. For Bowling Game, Friction coefficient between Ball and Lane is 0.12, what value I should assign to Ball and Lane in SceneKit as there is no option of setting static and dynamic friction as well as setting friction between system of 2 objects.

I can assign Friction for Ball between 0 and 1, but what does it represent, as According to physics friction can only be calculated between pair of objects and not single object

**Edit1**

I understand that I have to set values by trail and error, but I want to know how `SceneKit` resolves these values. 
e.g. in unity they are giving 4 option between 2 material (Average, Maximum, minimum, multiply)

Consider 2 objects A and B and their friction value is given by 0.1, 0.2
then

```
μAB = 0.1 (minimum)
μAB = 0.2 (maximum)
μAB = 0.15 (average)
μAB = 0.02 (multiply)
```

Please see this link https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using static for the lane (walls and floors), use dynamic for ball.  You can still set other properties for each. There is a lot more going on though - mass, gravity, rolling friction, damping, etc.

Friction is assigned to the object(s) itself and is calculated when the objects collide or roll/rub against each other.

Sorry I don't know the exact number to use- best guess is since they are both smooth surfaces, the numbers should be pretty close to the same. There are a number of things you have to be concerned with, so I'd start with the defaults and adjust from there.  After a bunch of trail and error, what I did was to overlay some UIKit controls over the top of scenekit to adjust the physics body properties on the fly and repeated the movements I wanted to test - then I adjusted the properties until I got the behavior I wanted.